# Select pairs of numbers with the minimum overall difference

Tags: algorithm, combinations, difference

Given *n* pairs of numbers, select *k* pairs so that the difference between the minimum value and the maximum value is minimal. Note that 2 numbers in 1 pair cannot be separated. Example *(n=5, k=3)*:

```
INPUT        OUTPUT (return the index of the pairs)
5 4          1 2 4
1 5
9 8
1 0
2 7
```

In this case, choosing *(5,4) (1,5) (1,0)* will give a difference of 5 *(max is 5, min is 0)*. I'm looking for an efficient way *(n log n)* of doing this since the input will be pretty large and I don't want to go through every possible case.

Thank you.

**NOTE:** No code is needed. An explanation of the solution is enough.

Comment: Do you want to print the indices of the chosen pairs in the solution or printing only the difference will do??

Comment: if k = 1, then output will be index 3 and difference would be 1??

Comment: @User_Targaryen Yes. If there are multiple solutions, any solution will do.

Comment: Could you provide the source of the problem?

Comment: @Tempux It was a problem in a national programming championship for high school students.

Comment: Yes I don't think you can get O(n logn) but there will be a lot of pruning in practice, if the search is implemented cleverly.

Comment: @maraca added O(n log n) solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a method with `O(n log n)` time complexity:

First sort the array according to the smaller number in the pair. Now iterate back from the last element in the sorted array (the pair with the highest minimum).

As we go backwards, the elements already visited will necessarily have an equal or higher minimum than the current element. Store the visited pairs in a max heap according to the *maximal* number in the visited pair. If the heap size is smaller than `k-1`, keep adding to the heap.

Once the heap size equals `k-1`, begin recording and comparing the best interval so far. If the heap size exceeds `k-1`, pop the maximal element off. The heap is guaranteed to contain the first `k-1` pairs where the minimal number is greater than or equal to the current minimal number and the maximal is smallest (since we keep popping off the maximal element when the heap size exceeds `k-1`).

Total time `O(n log n)` for sorting + `O(n log n)` to iterate and maintain the heap = `O(n log n)` in total.

Example:

```
5 4
1 5
9 8
1 0
2 7

k = 3

Sort pairs by the smaller number in each pair:
[(1,0),(1,5),(2,7),(5,4),(9,8)]

Iterate from end to start:
i = 4; Insert (9,8) into heap
i = 3; Insert (5,4) into heap
i = 2; Range = 2-9
i = 1; Pop (9,8) from heap; Range = 1-7
i = 0; Pop (2,7) from heap; Range = 0-5

Minimal interval [0,5] (find k matching indices in O(n) time)
```

Comment: Answers like this, deserve more upvotes in my opinion.

Comment: If you have k=1 and pairs  [(0,4),(5,6)] wouldn't your algorithm return [0,4]?

Comment: @AriHietanen thank you for your comment. Please describe how you see that process happening.

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes you are right it's correct. I just didn't read it carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Lets keep to sorted arrays: one which sorted according to minimal number in pair and other to maximal. Lets iterate over first array and fix minimal number in answer. We can keep pointer on k-th number in second array. When we go to next pair we remove all pairs with less minimal value from second array and forward pointer if needed. To find position in *log n* time in second array we can keep additional map between pair and position.